# Do I have to do all 50 waves in 1 go for it to count?

Tags: gears-of-war-3

My friend and I have been doing horde on insane but we do sets since I can't stay up late. For example, we did waves 1-16 first playthrough. Does this mean if we keep our pattern up we won't get anything for completing all 50 waves?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure (that's why this is a comment and not an answer), but I think you get all the rewards for beating all waves if you do it like you do.

Answer (score 2):

No, you will unlock any achievements/related rewards at the end for having completed all 50 waves, regardless of whether they were done in one go or not.  You can select a wave to begin from during the horde set-up menu.